# raise a signal with handlers registered on multiple processes

Tags: linux, operating-system, signals

Hi I am asking what will happen when a signal is raised with handlers registered on multiple processes? Will all process receive this signal or only one will receive it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signals are handled on a per-process basis.  However signals may be delivered to a multiple processes that belong to a process group

http://linux.die.net/man/2/killpg